# How can I resize the Chrome extension popup?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

EDIT: Fix was to use the property white-space = "white-space: nowrap".

Popup is to the left and to the right is how it looks as a regular html page. How can I make the popup look like the regular html page?

In the picture, there's css formatting, but I removed it all and the text keeps breaking that way.

[image: popup]

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 2):

It looks like not having `<!DOCTYPE html>` can cause similar problems. Check if you have it.

Otherwise, you can resize it dynamically like:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.width = ""+width;
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.height = ""+height;
```

or from CSS like this:

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks. I was able to fix it by simply adding the property "white-space: nowrap".